# Insert into table from stored procedure with different versions

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a stored procedure `sp` and a table variable `@tbl`

```
Insert into @tbl
  Exec sp
```

Above works fine initially.

We changed the stored procedure output and added additional output columns. The insert statement above fails with 2nd version of the stored procedure.

The above SQL needs to work with version 1 of `sp` and version 2 of `sp`

What can be done?

SQL Server doesn't provide the option to specify the column names while doing the insert from `sp` output

Comment: Not sure why someone would down vote this, it is a very good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do it is to use the `EXECUTE` `WITH RESULT SETS` to determine the exact columns to return from the stored procedure. This will give you the option to specify the column names to insert into the table variable from the stored procedure  output.

```
Insert into @tbl(col1, col2, col3) EXECUTE sp
WITH RESULT SETS (
    (col1 INT, 
     col2 INT,
     col3 nvarchar(50))
)
```

For more information, see [here](http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-execute-result-sets).